# How can I add Mockito to the test classpath in Tycho's unit-tests with eclipse-plugin packaging

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, junit, mockito, tycho

Recently, it has become possible to [Execute unit-tests with eclipse-plugin packaging](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572420). And, in addition there is [support for resolving JUnit Classpath Containers](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572602).

I would like to execute unit-tests with eclipse-plugin packaging, but would like to use the *mockito* library in addition to JUnit. I have a [pomless build](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/pomless) and would like to keep it that way. I do not want to add non-PDE files to the build, unless this is unavoidable.

**Question**: What is the idiomatic/intended/correct way to add this dependency, or any other test-time dependencies?

Note: I am aware of the use of `fragments` for unit testing. This is not what I am after. I actually want to use the new mechanism, if possible, or hear that this is currently impossible.

For my initial purposes, and given these are intended to be Unit-tests, running non-OSGI would be ok. If there is a means for OSGI as well, that would be great, but I cannot imagine where the platform configuration could be stored.

Comment: Run it as OSGi or non-OSGi?

Comment: non-OSGI. Sorry. Updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [tycho discussion](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/discussions/386), short summary:

- you can add Mockito as an optional bundle dependency
- you can add a [M2_REPO Classpath variable](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/pull/207) reference